# Set priority of the multiple jobs in jenkins

Tags: c#, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Hi have created multiple jobs for C# components. I have used pull machanish to build the jobs. As soon as developer check in the code into the SVN, Jenkins will start the build of that particular component. But the problems is, if we check-in multiple jobs together, then how Jenkins will manage the build priority. Any idea.

Answer (score 0):

does the jobs pull from the same repo? or is there 1 repo per your c# components? 
if there is 3 repos then each job is build at the same time, that is dependent on how many Build Executor you have configured

If you want to add a priority to your jobs you can install the Jenkins plugin "Priority Sorter Plugin", here is a link.

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Priority+Sorter+Plugin

Comment: There are separate repo for each component. I have 5 to 6 components

Comment: In that case, all 5/6 jobs will be kicked off at the same time. If you don't have 5/6 Build Executors then priority will be alphabetically (A first and so on). Is it possible to post a list of the job names?